Letters vs Digits: Should you write ‘Windows Seven’ or ‘Windows 7’ in an essay?
Is it Windows Seven or Windows 7 in an essay?
I’ve heard that numbers under ten should be spelled out with letters not digits, which suggests it should be Seven written with letters not just 7 written with digits.
However, I’ve seen the brand name of the operating system as Windows 7, like in its Wikipedia page here. So in an essay, should the number seven be spelled out with letters not digits?

I’m voting to close this question because it is a questions that can be easily answered by consulting a reputable online encyclopaedia or by accessing product data.

This isn't like seven Windows; the brand name is Windows 7, which is what you should use.
Google Ngram Viewer shows that Windows 7 tracks the lifetime of that OS version, whereas Windows Seven has no usage apparent.
On the other hand, the Austin Seven, although often referred to as Austin 7, had the full word on the car itself, as can be seen in this picture of one, so formally it's the Austin Seven.

I don't understand why users do not narrow searches, see ngram: 2000-2020

There didn't seem to be any need.

I'd argue the opposite, the string "Windows 7" could not have existed prior to 2000 unless it was or part of a book title.

So it would seem, but the posted default NGram shows my point clearly.

OED has examples from books with titles containing Windows 7:

Notebook computers can be used either as stand-alone computers or clients.
G. B. Shelly, Microsoft Windows 7 (2011)
Drives that are excessively fragmented are often subject to disk thrashing.
D. Gibson, Microsoft Windows 7 Desktop Support & Admin (2010)

As for using the name of the system in a sentence, OED gives example from newspapers:

I recently bought a computer running Windows 7, only to find that my Canon scanner no longer works because of the lack of a suitable driver.
Sunday Times
How to use a solid state disk (SSD) as the system disk on a Windows 7 computer.
Guardian Unlimited

Also, if you check NGram you will find too few instances of Windows seven in comparison with Windows 7, too few to be apprehensive to use the latter.
7 does not function here as a number but is part of the proper name of the system.

Sorry about the overlap: I had started writing and when you posted and didn't notice.

Yes, that's what happened. No worries. I am happy to delete my answer if irrelevant.

Most companies will publish guidance on how to properly use and display their logotype property.
https://ratnacahayarina.wordpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/microsoft.pdf

That may be so, but these are binding only on their employees and contractors; they don't have the authority to regulate how people at large speak or write. It is true, though, that it contributes to clarity if one is mindful of how the names of the products are spelled on the products themselves, their packaging, and in associated documentation (in this case, Windows Seven would be unnecessarily confusing, given that everybody is used to seeing the name written as Windows 7).
